# Categorizing Spend in Excel based on Trends in a Number of Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking to create a formula, if possible,  to identify trends and as a result return a specific category and sub-category. I'm not sure if this is possible so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have categorized spend that was done manually based on department, expenditure type, and account description. I'd like to find trends and terms so that I can, to some extent, automate this in the future. Based on these trends, it would return a category and sub category. Sample set below:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're trying to do.  Can you provide an example of what the output would be based on this data, and how you get there?

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the expected output with us, help us to fix  it !!

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to explain. I'll be receiving updated raw data monthly with the category and subcategory missing. I'm looking to populate this information based on existing trends in the expenditure org, type, and account description. Does that make sense?